# Assign a username to one of many PostgesSQL databases

Tags: postgresql, security, authorization, subscription

I'm planning a multiple PostgreSQL database application to reside on a single server.
The databases are identical structure and rules etc.
The data contained in each database is unique - belongs to a specific group of users (company or Organisation).
Client side is web browser/html or similar.

How do I manage connection and access to the user's assigned database?

I am guessing I have a web page for login, and then based on successful authorisation the user is connected to their assigned database.

The purpose is so as to centrally maintain databases (structure/process changes) and manage users by a monthly subscription, yet keep user groups data isolated from other groups.

I think Microsoft offer a multi-tenant SQL Server option which does this.
Also I think AWS offer similar for SAAS operations.

I am exploring my options.
I would like to implement and test before making any commitments.

I am open to suggestions/recommendations.

Thanks for any input in advance

Comment: In Postgres users are common to a cluster of databases. This means the users will be active across all the databases in the server. To properly manage this is out of the scope of a SO answer. I would search on 'postgresql multi tenancy' for more information.